# android andengine scene is slow when attache many childs to it?

Tags: android, andengine, physics, rectangles, scene

I am working on andengine application. In this i am inserting the sprites on user click and drawing a circle by using small rectangles. I create many rectangles by loop and arrange them on a path of circle, so it look like a circle. But the problem is screen is responding slowly and looks like hanging.Can anybody suggest how can i make it smoother..
Here is my code.

//variables

```
private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);


    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;

    private TiledTextureRegion mBoxFaceTextureRegion;

    private Scene mScene;

    private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
```

//scene method

```
@Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

        final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
        this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
        this.mScene.attachChild(left);
        this.mScene.attachChild(right);
        drawLine();
        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

        return this.mScene;
    }
```

//In drawline method:

```
private void drawLine() {


        float x1,y1,x2=1,y2=1;
        float r=100;
        float xCenter=300,yCenter=300;
        Rectangle rectTest;

        for(double i=0;i<5;i+=.01){
                x1 = (float) (xCenter + r * Math.cos(i));  
                y1 = (float) (yCenter + r * Math.sin(i));

                System.out.println("RECT x1="+x1);
                System.out.println("RECT y1="+y1);
                System.out.println("RECT x2="+x2);
                System.out.println("RECT y3="+y2);

             rectTest = new Rectangle(x1,y1,1,1,getVertexBufferObjectManager());

            rectTest.setColor(Color.RED);
            FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
                    0.1f, 0.1f);
            PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rectTest,
                    BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
            this.mScene.attachChild(rectTest);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are creating 500 dynamic body objects using Box2D. Box2D, or any physics engine, is relatively costly on a mobile platform. And simulating 500 colliding bodies is pushing the limit of what a mobile processor can handle. Try using under 50 objects to define your circle.

Comment: thanks Sturgeon for your quick response.Actually i am trying to draw a circle and with the capabilities of detecting the collision and wall properties (like a rectangle). So that i can detect the collision of a ball with the walls of the circle.So i decided to draw a circle by using rectangles .Is there any way to do the same task.Please suggest. i am stuck.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to make from your description, but I will suggest 2 things: 1 - there is a circle shape in Box2D you can use. and 2: you can use a program called PHYSICS EDITOR program to generate any shape polygon for your box2d project from a png image: I've used this for my own projects and highly recommend it.
http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Comment: is it available for ubuntu??

Comment: I don't know. You can ask the developer. The site only lists Mac and PC. Its not the only box2D editor out there. (you can also use Cocos2D for this sometimes) Just google around and find a tool. I recommend Physics Editor because I have used it and it worked.